# How to benchmark Linux threaded programs?

Tags: multithreading, performance, benchmarking, qemu

I'm trying to compare the performance of threaded programs (on Linux). Since the programs use different thread synchronization methods and different lock granularity, running the programs on a shared server or desktop would not be good, since the other tasks may interfere with the scheduling of my programs. I don't have dedicated hosts, so I thought that using qemu would be a good option.

What I want to know is:

- Are there any alternatives for this task?
- I suppose that there is no way to reproduce  scheduling  done by guest Linux system on qemu, if
  I - need to? (Suppose my program goes unusually skow or fast -- I'd like to know if I can run it again, but keeping exactly the same scheduling for its threads). Or is there a way?

Comment: I think the answer here is to do your performance tests over a long period of time so other tasks will be background noise.  Or if you are comparing multiple threaded programs then run them all with the same background tasks.

Comment: Have you had a look at the [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) tool suite? It offers callgrind for profiling and helgrind for thread debugging. Have not tried that myself yet, thus just a comment, on answer.